# Is it possible to disable part area of the touchscreen in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, touchscreen, hook

There is a laptop with screen touch function, but keeps ghost-touching as long as it is powered on.

I have tried many solutions like touching my hand on a window that is connected to the ground, adding a capacitor between VCC and GND, etc. But every attempt did not work. I am almost sure the problem is nothing to do with static charge.

Fortunately, I found the ghost-touching only happens at the last row of the screen aka the Y-coordinate=1080. So I want to disable the last row of the touching screen.

#### Related Info:

- Device Model: "alldocube mix plus" with both Electromagnetic and Capacitive touch screen.(A little-known Chinese brand, more device info: [HERE](https://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/e6853ff7))
- Operation System: Windows 10 1803
- The problem appears either when charging or not.

#### Potential Solution:

- Any way to modify some configuration of Windows or touchscreen driver to block certain touching area?
- Is there any software/tool providing such a function?
- Will a Windows global hook work with checking the coordinate of the touching message and blocking it? What message should I hook?

Comment: Would you mind adding the devices model to your question? There might be a fix that you haven't thought of.